# As apple's bug on -ObjC linker flag is fixed, do I need to add -all_load or -force_load to my project when using static libraries?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

The bug is demonstrated [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html). It said that for 64-bit and iPhone OS applications, there is a linker bug that prevents -ObjC from loading objects files from static libraries that contain only categories and no classes. The workaround is to use the -all_load or -force_load flags.

In fact, I don't know if the bug is fixed and I can't find anything about that. Is there somebody show me some apple's reference about the fixed bug ?

If the bug is really fixed, does it mean I do not need to add the -all_load (or -force_load) to my project when my static libraries contain only categories and no classes?

Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: why don't you test it?

Comment: @BradAllred I have tested it and I think it is fixed, but I don't know if is there some case I should use -all_load flag and I wan't a authoritative document to make sure the bug is fixed.

Comment: AFAIK, most of static lib are only using `-ObjC` flag now.

Comment: @BryanChen Thank you for your answer, I think apple has fixed the bug but didn't mention it.

Comment: @BryanChen To clear up a possible misconception: the linker flag `-ObjC` must be added to the target which links against the static library. So, adding it to a static lib has no effect at all.

Comment: This was fixed in Xcode 4 dot something, and for sure in v5. That said I distribute a static library that only uses categories on its OWN classes, and an app using it will crash without the flag. Ask me how I know this!

Comment: @DavidH Thank you for your answer! Why not write you answer below and more detail.

Comment: @DavidH Do you know what is it means by saying categories and no classes......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in Xcode 4 dot something, and for sure in Xcode 5. That said I distribute a static library that only uses categories on its OWN classes (and in separate files), and an app using it will crash without the flag. Ask me how I know this (one client forgot to add the flag!)

What "a category with no class" means that you have one file - a .m file implementation - and the only code in it is one or more categories. The converse would be a class implementation, followed by a category to that class. What is murky is a class implementation followed or preceded by a category to a different class - I will guess that would work but you'd have to test it.

You can actually experiment to see this in action! I actually added this to my static library so I could put out a warning if the -ObjC flag was missing (and you can do this too if you develop a library):

Create a global variable:

```
BOOL categoriesLoaded;
```

In one of your categories, add the following (and you could move this around to experiment)

```
@implementation SomeClass (SomeName)

+ (void)load
{
    categoriesLoaded = YES;
}
```

Then in a method of a primary library class, one that is sure to get called early on, test if the flag is set or not. If its not, the `-ObjC` flag was not set. You can then take some serious action, like log something and call exit(). If your categories were not loaded you will crash anyway, in some bizarre way in some code that will make no sense to any human looking at it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I know "categories and no classes" means a file just have category and no class implementation.